# Buffered Reader is not reading my whole file java

Tags: java

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\NormenYu\\Desktop\\Programming\\Java\\eclipse\\Book\\"+thebook+".txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();System.out.println(line);
```

My File:
(tab)You are on a hiking trip with your friend(also lives with you in a rented apartment). You suddenly find yourself walking into a jungle. As you walk, you suddenly find yourself very lonely. “Help!”, you heard.
(enter)(tab)“What was that,” you ask your friend. There is no reply. Wait... where is your friend? You start to find your way back, and suddenly you find your friend stuck in quicksand.

Do you: Walk towards your friend and try to save him or Stay away because you might also get stuck in quicksand

The program prints: You are on a hiking trip with your friend(also lives with you in a rented apartment). You suddenly find yourself walking into a jungle. As you walk, you suddenly find yourself very lonely. “Help!”, you heard.

HELP!! By the way, the things in parentheses are not written in the notepad.

Comment: Have you Googled how to use a BufferedReader to read a text file first? This is basic Java that can be found in most any tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [read file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796041/read-file-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a loop you can read each line in the file.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\NormenYu\\Desktop\\Programming\\Java\\eclipse\\Book\\"+thebook+".txt"));
String line;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
reader.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only reading in one line with the method `readLine`. You need to loop over the file until you reach the end. Something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while (in.ready()) {
  String s = in.readLine();
  System.out.println(s);
}
in.close();
```

Comment: This `while(in.ready())` is the condition that's working for me instead of `while(in.readLine() != null)` because it's giving me wrong line count.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\NormenYu\\Desktop\\Programming\\Java\\eclipse\\Book\\"+thebook+".txt"));

String full = "";

String line;
while ((line = reader .readLine()) != null) {
    full += line;
}

// full now contains the whole content of your file.
```